# ASP.NET 4 Routing File Extentions

Tags: asp.net, routes

How can I route  *.x2 to *2.jpg using ASP.NET 4 routhing no matter to its location?

gfx/test.x2 =>  gfx/test2.jpg

images/sample.x2 =>  images/sample2.jpg